# How to console.log entire HTML DOM tree in order with attribute names

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

So I am trying create a function, that will console.log the entire DOM tree of the HTML page. It is supposed to output the tag name of each HTML element in the order they appear - children before siblings + attribute name.

I have this working piece of code:

```
"use strict";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", traverse);

function traverse() {
    let elm = document.documentElement;
    displayInfo(elm);
};

function displayInfo(elm){
    //console.log(elm) 
    /* if (elm.childElementCount>0) {
        let children = Array.from(elm.children);
        console.log(children);
        children.forEach( displayInfo );
    }; */
    if (elm.hasAttributes) {
        //console.log(elm.attributes[0]);
    }; 
    var c = elm.childNodes;
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        console.log(c[i].nodeName);
        if (c[i].childElementCount>0) {
            //console.log(c[i].childElementCount);
            if (c[i].hasAttributes) {
                //console.log(c[i].attributes[0]);
            };
            let cc = c[i].children;
            let ii;
            for (ii=0; ii < cc.length; ii++) {
                console.log(cc[ii].nodeName);
                if (cc[ii].hasAttributes) {
                    //console.log(cc[ii].attributes[0]);
                };
                if (cc[ii].childElementCount>0) {
                    //console.log(cc[ii].childElementCount);
                    let ccc = cc[ii].children;
                    let iii;
                    for (iii=0; iii < ccc.length; iii++) {
                        console.log(ccc[iii].nodeName);
                        if (ccc[iii].hasAttributes) {
                            //console.log(ccc[iii].attributes[0]);
                        };
                        if (ccc[iii].childElementCount>0) {
                            //console.log(ccc[iii].childElementCount);
                            let cccc = ccc[iii].children;
                            let iiii;
                            for (iiii=0; iiii < cccc.length; iiii++) {
                                console.log(cccc[iiii].nodeName);
                                if (cccc[iiii].hasAttributes) {
                                    //console.log(cccc[iiii].attributes[0]);
                                };
                                if (cccc[iiii].childElementCount>0) {
                                    console.log(cccc[iiii].childElementCount)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 };
```

The problem is, I am horribly repeating myself, plus I am manually setting how "deep" it will traverse. Is there a way to declare only one function that traverse?

PS: I know it's horrible to look at, I was just making sure the function would "work" all the way.

Comment: Rather than `if (condition) { big block }`, you can `if (!condition) continue;` to reduce indentation hell.

Comment: And how would that look like in the example? I am sorry I am still not entirely familiar with the if statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an API just for this which is way more powerful than anything you could try to build yourself: [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker).

```js
var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
  document.documentElement,
  NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT // only elements
);
while (walker.nextNode()) {
  let current = walker.currentNode;
  console.log(
    current.tagName,
    [...current.attributes].map(({value,name}) => `${name}=${value}`).join()
  );
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div id="container">container content
    <span>one span</span>
    <span class="nest1">nest1 span<span class="nest2">nest2 span</span></span>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: This! hundred times this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to add this simple log of all nodes in a document object element names id and classes included placed in a neat array.

`console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('*'));`

Comment: I will edit my answer to include full use case after work

Answer (score 1):

Note that `hasAttributes` is a *function*, not a property. `element.hasAttributes` will always be `true`.

Use recursion, like this:

```js
function displayInfo(node) {
  console.log(node.nodeName);
  if (node.nodeType === 3) {
    console.log('Text node: ' + node.textContent);
    return;
  }
  if (node.hasAttributes()) {
    [...node.attributes].forEach(({ name, value }) => console.log(`${name}=${value}`));
  }
  node.childNodes.forEach(displayInfo);
}
displayInfo(document.documentElement);
```

```html
<article>
<div id="container">container content
<span>one span</span>
<span class="nest1">nest1 span<span class="nest2">nest2 span</span></span>
</div>
</article>
```

The `continue` shortcut I mentioned would look like this, to start with:

```
for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
  console.log(c[i].nodeName);
  if (c[i].childElementCount === 0) continue;
  //console.log(c[i].childElementCount);
  if (c[i].hasAttributes) {
    //console.log(c[i].attributes[0]);
  };
  let cc = c[i].children;
```

Avoid indentation when you can - you'll make your code a lot more readable.

Comment: Ok this somewhat works, but now it ignores other nodes than type 3 and goes directly for the textContent. What I am looking for is something, that will start all the way at the document Node, check for attributes (and if it has any - console.log them) then check for children and console.log them and then go deeper and deeper and deeper. This is actually pretty good because your code goes for the text, which is something I was not able to do before, but Now It does not log the names of the parent nodes like HTML, HEAD (meta, title) and BODY (section..) and so on.

Comment: Just call it on `documentElement` instead.

Comment: and by the shortcut, do you mean those three dots ...?

Comment: Not at all, it's just as I said - a way to reduce indentation hell.